# Force Authentication in Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, oauth-2.0

we are running into an issue that once our users are login in the app and are authenticated thru the oauth flow the authentication page is never being displayed again, in that way user cannot switch account if needed. We are using a popup display mode (which does not provide options to switch user) and "switch user" small button in top right side of the screen is not appearing in our mobile small screen devices (as Iphones). We tried the auth_type=reauthenticate but it does not provide any option to switch user in popup mode either. We can´t control user´s cookies as well so there is not how to delete them. Is there any way to always ask user to reathenticate during all oauth requests allowing user to switch accounts?

Answer (score 0):

If Facebook has implemented OpenID Connect correctly, try to add `prompt=login` or `prompt=select_account` to your authorization request. See "[3.1.2.1. Authentication Request](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest)" in [OpenID Connect Core 1.0](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) for details.